# Send a FIN packet to notify that the data was sent

Tags: c#, node.js, sockets, tcp

I have a Windows service that constantly sends data to a NodeJS streamer that then transmits that data to clients.

On the NodeJS streamer I am listening to the socket event "data":

```
socket.on('data', function ...
```

And inside that function I bundle all of the received packets to a string.
After that all the relevant packets have been received, I want to operate on that string and then transmit it to the client.

To do that, I try to listen to the "end" event:

```
socket.on('end', function ...
```

But the "end" event is never called.
I read that I have to initiate a FIN packet to the NodeJS streamer in order to invoke the "end" event and to do that I have to close the stream writer on the C# service.
However, I am handling with a lot of data for many different clients and I am afraid that closing the writer each time I am done with a single string would create a big overhead. Is it a legitimate concern? If so, is there another way to send a FIN packet?

Thanks,
Arik

Answer (score 0):

FIN indicates the (graceful) end of the TCP connection. It sounds like you just need to frame your packets in some way if you want to send multiple "messages" per connection. There's many ways to go about doing that, but it all depends on your needs. A couple of examples:

- Prefix each "message" with a fixed number of length bytes that tell how many bytes follow for the entire "message." The number of fixed length bytes depends on the maximum amount of data you plan on transferring for a given "message."
- Use some sort of delimiter. This will depend on the type of data you're transferring. If it's binary data, this will not be a good option. If it's binary data, you could perhaps use a null byte or maybe a newline (depending on your text content).